# Was there a first biological cell on earth? or a similar cell originated simultaneously around the world?

Tags: evolution, cell-biology

It logically follows that if life began on earth and life is cellular, then either that life began singularly or began simultaneously around the world?

What is the evidence or argument for either position?

Or is it both?

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. On this site (for  biology researchers, academics, and students) we expect posters to conduct their own research before posting to try to answer the question themselves. You must have realized that this topic would have been raised and discussed before, and you may even find similar questions on this site. Have you looked?

Comment: @David Yes I knew this would have been thought of before however my only access to information is via the Internet and mainly Wikipedia I know there is a lot of information on the Web however it is just the Web and not an area where professional information is usually published. Not being a professional biologist I do not have access to biological papers so I thought this would be the best place where I could gather information that iam curious about. I will look through the posts on this site if you wanted to close the question.

Comment: or its a no one knows question.

Comment: The technical term for the origin of life from non-living matter is "abiogenesis". If you search this site with that term you will see a list of questions, including a very active one from ten years ago, entitled ["Why did abiogenesis only happen once?"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/14175/why-did-abiogenesis-only-happen-once). You might check this out.

Comment: @David Thanks for the referral. Having read the question that you suggested I look at. Do you think it would be possible to simulate the conditions however speculative they are, that life began with?

Comment: @David I have just looked and the question of a large scale simulated abiogenesis has been asked before.